# Solr: generated field score vs doc property score

Tags: solr

My documents have a field `"score"` which is `double` type.
I want to get results by `sorting` on this field.

But when i try `sort score desc` or `sort score asc`, it doesn't seem to sort on the document `score` field, rather, it seems to sort on the solr generated `score` field for each doc.

How can i achieve sorting on the doc field?

Comment: for the time being, i have changed the field name to "custom_score" (or any other identifier except score)